# can I use state hook in loadfunction of devexpress grid? (react)

Tags: reactjs, loops, grid, state, devexpress

I am trying to set data in `loadFunction`, but then `getData` function is called infinitely.
If I don't use state, then it is fine.

here is my code:

```
 const getData = async (options) => {
    if (!options.filter || !options.filter.length || !columns.length) {
      setdataLength(0);
      return {
        data: [],
        totalCount: 0,
      };
    }
    const resp = await axios.post("/Transactions/Get", options);

    setdataLength(resp.data.totalCount)

    return resp.data;
  };
```

```
<div style={{ position: "relative" }} className="grid-table-wrapper">
          <Grid
            withCustomStore={true}
            keyExpr={"ID"}
            storeKey={"ID"}
            loadFunction={getData}
            scrollMode={"none"}
            customColumns={columns}
            filterOptions={{ filterRow: true, headerFilter: false }}
            refresh={forceUpdate}
            pagerOptions={{
              defaultPageSize: 20,
              visible: dataLength <= 20 ? false : true,
              allowedPageSizes: [20, 40, 60, "all"],
              showPageSizeSelector: dataLength <= 20 ? false : true,
              showInfo: true,
              showNavigationButtons: true,
            }}
          />
          {dataLength === 0 && (
            <div className={BetsScss.noData}>
              <NoData />
              <h3>No results found</h3>
              <p>
                Try adjusting your search or filter to find what you're looking
                for.
              </p>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
```

I tried useRef instead of states, but it doesnt works. I need to re render Grid.